# Convert Environment Variable To Script Arguments

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to provide a configuration layer to my users by allowing them to specify an environment variable with command line options. This config is actually for a wrapper program (`run.sh`) which receives the arguments and then invokes my program (`program.sh`).

I am having a problem with the arguments maintaining their quotations, which causes unexpected arguments to be passed through.

Here is an example implementation:

**run.sh**

```
exec `pwd`/program.sh ${CONFIG} "$@"
```

**program.sh**

```
for var in "$@"
do
    echo "$var"
done
```

An example invocation would look like this:

```
$> CONFIG='--foo="bar baz quo" --foo2="bar2 baz2"' ./run.sh hello abc123    
--foo="bar
baz
quo"
--foo2="bar2
baz2"
hello
abc123
```

I would have expected output like:

```
--foo="bar baz quo"
--foo2="bar2 baz2"
hello
abc123
```

I have tried wrapping ${CONFIG} in run.sh in qoutes, but that just makes a single argument of `--foo="bar baz quo" --foo2="bar2 baz2"`. Escaping the quotations inside of `CONFIG` also yields an incorrect result.

Comment: Where does the `abc123` come from?

Comment: The environment is not the right way to pass arguments like this.

Comment: @cdarke the `abc123` got put on the wrong line, updating the question to reflect that.

Comment: You can't do this safely. This is a problem with system init scripts as well and has been for ages. The only way to pass space-safe arguments is with an array which you can't export but *could* pass by name in some contexts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`run.sh`

```
eval exec `pwd`/program.sh "${CONFIG}" "$@"
```

`program.sh`

```
for var                     # The 'in "$@"' is not required, it is the default
do
    echo "$var"
done
```

Output:

```
$ CONFIG='--foo="bar baz quo" --foo2="bar2 baz2"' ./run.sh hello 
--foo=bar baz quo
--foo2=bar2 baz2
hello
```

Note sure where the `abc123` in your output is supposed to come from.

Comment: This is risky as `CONFIG` variable is coming from external users. Once can set `CONFIG='$(rm program.sh); --foo="bar baz quo" --foo2="bar2 baz2"'`